# Understanding new word

Tags: meaning

I'm learning English as my second language. 
Now I want to improve my vocabulary by reading because I have heard that the best and the fastest way to explode

vocabulary is reading as much as possible. I have been following this advice.

But I have a problem of understading. While I am reading a small sentence, I catch a word which I don't know what it

means, I use my dictionary application (Longman, Cambridge) to translate it, after that, I find a new word in the

definition, and I search with this new word, oh no, I find another new word,...so on.  Finally, I still don't know what the

sentence means.

I'm very stupid or something's wrong?
What should I do?

Comment: Sometimes it is better to just leave the dictionary closed if the explanation confuses you. Focus on understanding the _text_ you are reading, not every single word or sentence. It doesn't matter if there are some words that you do not understand, or even if there are some sentences that you do not (fully) understand, as long as you understand the text. Trying to understand words _in context_ is faster and works better than looking up every word in a dictionary. That said, I think your question would be better asked at our [sister site](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You may be able to find parallel texts with English on one page and your native-language equivalent (NLE) on the facing page. Reading such texts can greatly speed up vocabulary-building, as follows: 1) Read the English text, covering over the NLE text so that you won't be tempted to look at it too soon; 2) When you get to a word or sentence that you can't understand, take a good look at it and try to work out its meaning from the context and your existing knowledge of word roots, prefixes etc.; 3) If that fails, or you want to check whether you guessed right, only then look at the NLE text.

Comment: It's a lot simpler learning one's first language as an infant, because one doesn't feel embarrassed by the simple exercises one is subjected to. But childrens books (I left out the apostrophe for a reason) are still generally better suited for learners of any age.

Comment: @dnvThai, Oerkelens is absolutely correct. Leave your dictionary closed. If you don't undertsand a word just move on. Try to understand the general meaning of the sentence or paragraph. If you don't understand a very large amount of words (more than 5-10%) then the text you're reading is too difficult. Try to use graded readers. Normally you will find that you don't understand a word the first time. After seeing it a couple more times, you'll have an idea. After that you will understand it completely!

Comment: I would reinforce the comment by @Edwin regarding books for children. I find them excellent for learning other languages, partly because of the graduated learning process, but also because they convey basic cultural knowledge. But in general, just keep reading. My father told me, after innumerable requests for explanations, *just call it a wheelbarrow - it's real meaning will become obvious from the way it's used*.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try much more. As oerkelens said, but if I shouldn't use dictionary, I also don't understand, that may make me never know what the word's meaning? I should keep going to read and I will understand oneday?

Comment: Who has said that you shouldn't use a dictionary? We all do. On ELU, probably more than most other people. But (1) hearing proficient speakers use English, (2) reading decent literature of an appropriate level are even more important. And in that order.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, when I knew too few words.
I agree that reading is very important.
And trying to guess what a word means is important as well
So I'm using the next algorithm:
if I don't know the word I try to guess what it means. 
If I can't I look it up in the Eng-Eng dictionary and try to understand or to guess again.
If I fail I look it up in the Eng-my_native_language dictionary.
I write down this word and try to learn/remeber it, in order to remember it when I stumble on it next time.
This way I can focus on the book and what it is about, rather than just words.
And this approach has another advantage, when I finish reading a book, I want to try next one. So one little success help to keep motivation.

Comment: I'm wondering how do an England person learn their language? They don't have "Eng-my_native_language".